# How to fix the screen

Tags: vb6

I am starting a project in VisualBasic 6, in which I need to add more TextBox / CheckBox / ComboBox through a button. The problem is that when you add them, the screen is unpacked. I enclose the images for better compression:

This is the form created (What is inside the Frame should be displayed after pressing the button. (Index at 0 and visible at false)):

[image]

When I start the application it looks like this:

[image]

And when I press the button this happens:

[image]

[image]

The idea is that it looks like in the first image, in which I show the created form. This is all the code I use:

```
Dim index As Integer

Private Sub btnAdd_Click ()
index = index + 1 'we increase the index

Load UserControl1 (index)'here is the error
UserControl1 (index) .Visible = True
UserControl1 (index) .Top = UserControl1 (index - 1) .Top + UserControl1 (index - 1) .Hight + 20 'this not work to me. Error: Sub or Function not defined

'frmAdd
Load frmAdd (index) 'we create the control
frmAdd (index) .Visible = True 'we make it visible
frmAdd (index) .Top = frmAdd (index - 1) .Top + frmAdd (index - 1) .Height + 20
'frmAdd (index) .Top = frmAdd (index - 1) .Top + frmAdd (index) .Height move the control

'cmbAddType
Load cmbAddType (index)
Set cmbAddType (index) .Container = frmAdd (index)
cmbAddType (index) .Visible = True
cmbAddType (index) .Top = cmbAddTipo (index - 1) .Top
'cmbAddType (index) .Top = cmbAddTipo (index - 1) .Top + cmbAddType (index) .Height

'txtAddPrefix
Load txtAddPrefix (index)
Set txtAddPrefix (index) .Container = frmAdd (index)
txtAddPrefix (index) .Visible = True
txtAddPrefix (index) .Top = txtAddPrefix (index - 1) .Top

'txtAddNumber
Load txtAddNumber (index)
Set txtAddNumber (index) .Container = frmAdd (index)
txtAddNumber (index) .Visible = True
txtAddNumber (index) .Top = txtAddNumber (index - 1) .Top

'checkAddPrincipal
Load checkAddPrincipal (index)
Set checkAddPrincipal (index) .Container = frmAdd (index)
checkAddPrincipal (index) .Visible = True
checkAddPrincipal (index) .Top = checkAddPrincipal (index - 1) .Top

'cmbAdd Link
Load cmbAdd Link (index)
Set cmbAdd Link (index) .Container = frmAdd (index)
cmbAdd Link (index) .Visible = True
cmbAddLink (index) .Top = cmbAddLink (index - 1) .Top

End Sub
```

Add image to my UserControl:

[image]

Not `Visible` property in UserControl:

[image]

Not `Index` property in UserControl:

[image]

Comment: You can bundle your frame and its controls into a User Control to make it simpler to add new instances of all of these controls. You can use `Load` to load new instances of your user control, the same way you are doing here.

Comment: I agree with Etienne's approach.  It's a better way to go.  The issues with your code include 1) the index on the Height property should be `index - 1` and 2) the child controls are not being added to the new Frame.

Comment: Can you show me a example? @ÉtienneLaneville

Comment: You can start by creating the user control by adding one to your project from the Project menu: Project > Add User Control. Then move (cut and paste) the controls (combo boxes, textboxes, etc) from your frame to the user control. It looks like you will probably want to use the same user control for the top part of your form. You can lookup "VB6 User Controls" on Google, you will find plenty of example on how to use them.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but my boss doesn't want that, he wants it on the same screen @ÉtienneLaneville

Comment: Once you have built your user control, you can add it to your main form as you would a frame and other controls. Research this a little more, you will understand how user controls work and you will see why this approach will simplify things for you.

Comment: Thank you @ÉtienneLaneville

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can solve the problem at least 2 ways:  either fixing your approach or adopting Etienne's approach.  To fix your approach try the following code.  The main fixes were setting the `Container` property for child controls and adjusting the `Top` calculation:

```
Private Sub btnAdd_Click()
   index = index + 1

   Load Frame1(index)
   Frame1(index).Visible = True
   Frame1(index).Top = Frame1(index - 1).Top + Frame1(index - 1).Height + 20

   Load Command1(index)
   Set Command1(index).Container = Frame1(index)
   Command1(index).Visible = True
   Command1(index).Top = Command1(index - 1).Top

   'etc, etc, etc
End Sub
```

An easier approach is to use UserControl's.  With this approach your code becomes:

```
Private Sub btnAdd_Click()
   index = index + 1

   Load UserControl11(index)
   UserControl11(index).Visible = True
   UserControl11(index).Top = UserControl11(index - 1).Top + UserControl11(index - 1).Height + 20
End Sub
```

Comment: i created a user control with the name UserControl and i add the lines in the button but when i click the button the program shows me this: `Sub or Function procedure not defined`

Comment: Try changing the name.  In my sample, the UserControl is named `UserControl1` in the project tree.  When I drop it on the form, it becomes `UserControl11` and then I set the Index to 0.  Probably a name of `UserControl` is conflicting with VB.

Comment: And i try with the first case but don't shows me the text boxes, etc. The program only show the frame but not the others things when i press the button

Comment: Did you set the `Container` property for child controls?  And adjust the `Top` calculation?

Comment: I added the new code to you can understand the errors. And thank you for your help

Comment: Did you place this UserControl on the form like you would any other control?  And once placed on the form, did you set the `Index` to 0 and `Visible` to False?

Comment: UserControl don't have a index or visible property. I add image in the question

Comment: Drop the control on the form, click on it on the form, and then you will see the properties you need.

Comment: If i change the properties of the form to visible=false, when i run app the form don't appears

Comment: Once created, the UserControl is like any other control, such as the Frame control you originally used.  It will show up in the Toolbox palette and can be dropped onto the form.  Once dropped onto the form, it will have a name like `UserControl11`.  Select this control you dropped onto the form and set the Index and Visible properties.  Do not change the properties of the form itself.

Comment: Not to me, The properties of UserControl not shows me options visible or index. Look the images in the question

Comment: Do not select the UserControl in the Project Tree.  Select the one you dropped onto the form.  Carefully read my last response again.